AppleClang 15: no member named 'fetch_add' in 'std::atomic<float>'
I have a C++20 program that can be successfully built in Ubuntu 20 with GCC 10 or in Visual Studio 2019. And now I need to compile it for macOS 13.7.2 x64 (currently available on GitHub-hosted runner), which possesses AppleClang 15 compiler.
The program uses std::atomic<float> data types, and fetch_add operation for them as in the example:
#include <atomic>

int main() {
    std::atomic<float> a{0};
    a.fetch_add(1);
}

Unfortunately, it fails to compile in AppleClang 15 with the

error: no member named 'fetch_add' in 'std::atomic'

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8WvGrczq7
I would like to keep std::atomic<float> data types in the program (to minimize the changes), but replace fetch_add with something else available (probably less performant). Is there such workaround for old Clangs with libc++?


Is there such workaround for old Clangs?

As commented, std::compare_exchange_weak is available for your clang version.
#include <atomic>

float fetch_add(std::atomic<float>& a, float val) {
    float expected = a;
    while( !a.compare_exchange_weak(expected, expected + val)) {}
    return expected;
}

int main() {
    std::atomic<float> a{0};
    fetch_add(a,1);
}


The libc++ status page for C++20 shows that P0019 (the paper that added std::fetch_add) was implemented for clang 19.

Note that the latest apple clang version (16) is based on llvm 17 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-12.x(since_Free_On-Device_Development)

Slight correction: P0019 was std::atomic_ref.  The paper on std::atomic<floating-point-type>, including fetch_add for such, was P0020, which libc++ reports as implemented in version 18.  Still too new for OP though.
